# search and edit xml based on attrib

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to search a XML based on id, and then add a tag for the one which the id matches my search.
Currently I have this xml

```
<tag>qw</tag>


-<work>

    <label id="1"/>

    <label id="2"/>

    <label id="3"/>


 -<search>

    <since>0</since>

    <to>1</to>

    <input>a</input>

</search>


-<search>

    <since>0</since>

    <to>1</to>

    <input>a</input>

</search>

</work>

</structure>
```

I need to chance, for example, the one with id="1"

```
  <label id="1">
    <mynewtag/>
  </label>
```

Any idea how to do that? thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that the XML has been read in some way.  Would you be accepting of a solution which reads in the XML, adds in the element, and then returns a new XML output?

Comment: yeah, i did read the xml and put the elements in there. sure, that solution would be fine

Comment: You say that you want to add a tag.  But the label you have shown is self-closing.  Do you want it to look like `<label id="1"><mynewtag/></label>` or just have the new tag following the id?

Comment: my bad, my example wasn't right. I edited it, label isnt self closing, mynewtag has to be inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a parser is the way to go here.  I'm most comfortable with `lxml` so that's what I'll be using in my answer here, but there are others you may choose from.

`import lxml.etree as ET`

The first thing to do is to have the XML read in somehow.  Here, I just assumed it is in a string.

```
xml = """<structure>
    <work>
        <label id="1"/>
        <label id="2"/>
        <label id="3"/>
        <search>
            <since>0</since>
            <to>1</to>
            <input>a</input>
        </search>
        <search>
            <since>0</since>
            <to>1</to>
            <input>a</input>
        </search>
    </work>
</structure>"""
```

Now the actual work can be done on it.  First we parse the tree so that we aren't working on raw text and are instead working on a structured object.  We'll be using a special parser to be able to get a nice printed output later.  More details may be found [here](https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output).

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = ET.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
```

So now we have a nice tree structure to work with.  We need to find the label that you are targeting to change.  To find the label in question, I'll be using XPATH.  XPATH isn't exactly the smoothest process if you're not familiar with it so I'd recommend looking into how to select exactly what you want.  [Here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/xpath-tutorial/topics/xpath-tutorial.html) is a pretty good tutorial with interactive examples that you can play around with.  I believe the examples are in HTML but the ideas are transferable.  In our example here, we're finding a label with an id of 1.

`target = tree.find(".//label[@id='1']")`

Next order of business is to create new tag.  You can add attributes as you please but for a minimal example, we'll just add a simple tag called "mynewtag".

`mynewtag = ET.Element("mynewtag")`

Let's add in the created tag to the label we found earlier.  Since there is just one element, I'll be using append.  However, if order matters to you (for example, you want it to be the first child of some other element), you may use insert instead of append.

`target.append(newtag)`

Now the changes have been made to the tree!  All that's left to do is to print out the resulting XML.  We turn the tree back into a string and then print it out.  The decode call is because the `tostring` method returns a byte-string and I want the newlines to be properly rendered.  The `pretty_print` option makes the output...pretty.

`print(ET.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode("UTF-8"))`

And with that we're done!  Our output is shown below.

```
<structure>
  <work>
    <label id="1">
      <mynewtag/>
    </label>
    <label id="2"/>
    <label id="3"/>
    <search>
      <since>0</since>
      <to>1</to>
      <input>a</input>
    </search>
    <search>
      <since>0</since>
      <to>1</to>
      <input>a</input>
    </search>
  </work>
</structure>
```

If you have any other concerns feel free to ask.

Comment: Happy to help :)